# BS4 cant find text

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to print this text https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrjl0.png
I used "soup.find_all("p", class_="review")" and tried to use .getText or check inside .contents but none of them worked

web link https://m.wuxiaworld.co/Castle-of-Black-Iron/

here is some debug info https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mS7d.png

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def info(novelname):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
    url = "https://m.wuxiaworld.co/"+novelname+"/"
    headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, features="html.parser")
    for textp in soup.find_all("p", class_="review"):
        print textp.contents
        print textp
        print textp.getText()
```

Comment: Can you share the source or source url?

Comment: no problem im going to edit

Comment: u can check now.

Comment: please do not links to code, just put it into your question

Comment: updated im kinda of new

Comment: please post an url for a book so we can test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict

def info(novelname):        
    response = requests.get(
        'https://m.wuxiaworld.co/{}/'.format(novelname.replace(' ', '-')),
        headers=OrderedDict(
            (
                ("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7"),
                ("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"),
                ("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5"),
                ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate"),
                ("Connection", "keep-alive"), 
                ("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1")
            )
        )
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

        for textp in soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'review'}):
            print textp.text.strip()

info('Castle of Black Iron')
```

Problem was your html parser... using html5lib gives us

```
Description

After the Catastrophe, every rule in the world was rewritten.

In the Age of Black Iron, steel, iron, steam engines and fighting force became the crux in which human beings depended on to survive.

A commoner boy by the name Zhang Tie was selected by the gods of fortune and was gifted a small tree which could constantly produce various marvelous fruits. At the same time, Zhang Tie was thrown into the flames of war, a three-hundred-year war between the humans and monsters on the vacant continent. Using crystals to tap into the potentials of the human body, one must cultivate to become stronger.

The thrilling legends of mysterious clans, secrets of Oriental fantasies, numerous treasures and legacies in the underground world — All in the Castle of Black Iron!

Citadel of Black Iron
黑铁之堡
```

Answer (score 0):

When you print your soup you will see some html tags in terminal (not all source).I think the website hides some part of datas.So I recommend to use Selenium.
If you haven't download yet you can install on :

```
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/
```

All code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = r'your driver path'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)


browser.get("https://m.wuxiaworld.co/Castle-of-Black-Iron/")

x = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("p[class='review']") ## Declare which class
for text1 in x:
    print text1.text
browser.close()
```

OUTPUT :

> Description
>       After the Catastrophe, every rule in the world was rewritten. In the Age of Black Iron, steel, iron, steam engines and fighting force
>   became the crux in which human beings depended on to survive. A
>   commoner boy by the name Zhang Tie was selected by the gods of fortune
>   and was gifted a small tree which could constantly produce various
>   marvelous fruits. At the same time, Zhang Tie was thrown into the
>   flames of war, a three-hundred-year war between the humans and
>   monsters on the vacant continent. Using crystals to tap into the
>   potentials of the human body, one must cultivate to become stronger.
>   The thrilling legends of mysterious clans, secrets of Oriental
>   fantasies, numerous treasures and legacies in the underground world —
>   All in the Castle of Black Iron! Citadel of Black Iron 黑铁之堡

Comment: well i was determined to mastered bs so i really dont want to use other source

Comment: bs is a good library but can not provide everything.Using other libs can solve the problem better.For instance, if u wanna fetch some datas in website that is in the script, u need to use selenium. @JonathanSmith